# holderjs show text and size at the same time

Tags: image, text, placeholder, holder.js

I use [holderjs](https://github.com/imsky/holder) to generate a placeholder image for my site.

`<img data-src="holder.js/200x200" />` will show up an image with text "200x200" and `<img data-src="holder.js/200x200?text=hello"` can display the image with text "hello".

Is there any way to show up the image size and custom text together(don't set the text as something like "200x200 hello")??

Thanks~

Update: 06/25/2015

Git the response from the developer of dustjs as below

> If you need to be sure that whitespace is left between two elements (for example, inline-block elements or inside white-space: pre blocks, you can use the Dust special {~s} to insert a space. You can also leave trailing whitespace at the end of a line if your editor allows it. Dust will not strip trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <img  data-src="holder.js/200x200?text=hello&fg=#FF0000&size=50" alt='Thumbnail' class="big"/>
```

It will show size within text and color

---

**update 1:**

put image tag in div tag with class "holderjs"

```
<div class="holderjs" data-background-src="?holder.js/300x200">
<img  data-src="holder.js/300x200/?text=hello" alt='Thumbnail' class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" text="hello" />

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Attribute `size` just resize the font-size while `fg` changes the color.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not currently possible to do, there is an issue to Holder to implement this in 2.9: https://github.com/imsky/holder/issues/148

Edit: this is now implemented.

Comment: Yes, I opened that issue :). I've created a koa middleware to meet my requirement.